# NSMutableAttributedString doesn't show string in different color for some specific range in iOS 8 & iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I am using attributes string in my code. To set font & color of text for some specific range. 
For this I am using below code. 
Font is working for range but color is not set for that range. There may be some issue in `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Please let me know if anyone have solution.

[image: See font of "New" is set but not color]

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor] };


NSMutableAttributedString *titleStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"New Message from Test"];
                [titleStr addAttributes:attrs range:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
```

Comment: Font size is working but color is not.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code. I just used your code and it works fine. [See here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tsPV3.png)

Comment: @RamarajT I test it but it is not working

Comment: How do u use the titlStr? Do you set it to any UILabel? Did you try to debug and hover the titleStr like I did?

Comment: I have to set it on label. Yes I did. Wait I am sharing screenshot

Comment: That looks odd. What do you got while debugging? Hover over the titleStr before setting it to the label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92818/discussion-between-ramaraj-t-and-nilesh-iosdev).

Comment: New{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb28b01af90> font-family: \".SFUIText-Regular\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
} ee ee (7894564560){
}

Comment: @Nilesh_iOSDev i have used ur code.. its running perfectly in my iOS 8.4 simulator.

Comment: @Nilesh_iOSDev If my answer helped you, plz accept my answer. Bcoz someone flags my answer as a comment everyday

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the similar problem. So I passed my string as HTML string and got it done like this.

```
NSString *name = @"<center><font color='#cd1c5f' size='4px'>"
                 @"New"
                 @"</font>"
                 @"<font color='#000000' size='4px'>"
                 @"Message from test"
                 @"</font></center>";

NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[name dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

_lbl_nm.attributedText=attrStr;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`?

Comment: to pass multiple html string. in place of concatenation, do let me know if therez any other way to do so..

Comment: Well instead of having 6 literal strings, you can simply have one.  You can use `NSString *name = @"first" @"second" ... @"sixth"` (with a newline between each literal).  The compiler will concat the strings automatically.

Comment: Hey thanks it really worked. I m newbie in this field m still learning. Thanks a ton for this piece of precious information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are changing the textcolor of the label **after** you set the attributed title. Thats the only way you will face this problem. Do it **before** you set the title.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.textLabel.attributedText = titleStr;
```

I don't see any problems with your code. I just copied your code and tested, everything's fine.

[image]

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I chatted with the questioner, this is what his problem. He resets the textColor after he sets the attributed title.

Comment: Seriously?  He doesn't call `setAttributedText:` with the new string? That's ridiculous.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JAL No, see the last line of my answer, The questioner did reset the textColor after he resets the attributed title. That's what his problem was. I chatted with him.

Answer (score 0):

You can append two attribute string with different attributes of red colour & text colour. Lets try using the following code chunk.

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]};
NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"New" attributes:attrDict] autorelease];
attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor lightTextColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]};
NSAttributedString *messageString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" Message from Test" attributes:attrs] autorelease];
[titleString appendAttributedString:messageString];
[self.titleTextView setAttributedText:titleString];
```